# Maximum and minimum points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{m} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that there exists directional derivative in any point of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. If $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u)>0$ for all $u \in S^{m-1}$ then theres exists a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a) = 0$ for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

I know that $f$ attains maximum and minimum in $S^{m-1}$, because $S^{m-1}$ is a compact set and $f$ continuous. Also, I know that if $x$ is a maximum or minimum point,$f'(x)=0$ when $f:I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $I$ a real interval. How do I use this informations? Thanks for the any help!

Comment: The minimum on the closed ball is attained. At that point the directional derivatives are zero.

Comment: @fourRightRotations The minimum is attained because $f$ is increasing on the ball, since directional derivatives are positive?

Comment: The minimum is attained because $f$ is continuous and the closed ball is compact. And I mean the unit ball $\{x:\ \|x\|\leq 1\}$. On $S^{m-1}$ there is no point with all derivatives zero, by assumption. The assumption tells you that, in particular, the minimum on the ball is not on the boundary, which is important for showing that the derivatives are zero there.